# DropDownList to filter table MVC 5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, drop-down-menu

I am in need of some help on how I can solve this problem. I've been trying several things, but I'm getting nowhere.
Here's my problem: I want to use a `dropdownlist` with the table I created with EF in MVC 5. The `dropdownlist` contains the `ContactGroups` created by the user. This `dropdownlist` will change depending on the unique values in my database. When I choose between the `ContactGroups` in the `dropdownlist`, I want the table to show only contacts that belong to the selected `ContactGroup`. For example: if I click on "Friends" in the `dropdownlist`, I want the table to show only contacts with `ContactGroup` value as "Friends".

My question: What is the best way to implement this?  How can I get the value selected in `DropDownList`? Is it best practice to send this value back to the controller and filter out the Contacts? Should I use Partial Views?

**View**

```html
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Webassistent.Models.ContactModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Contacts"; 
}

<h2>Contacts</h2>

@Html.DropDownList("CG",
(@ViewBag.Groups) as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select Group",
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })


<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Contact", FormMethod.Get)) {
  <p>
    Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </p>
}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>
        First Name
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Last Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
      </th>
      <th>
        Private Phone
      </th>
      <th>
        Private Email
      </th>
      <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("ContactGroup", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.GroupSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
      </th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrivatePhone)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PrivateEmail)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactGroup)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ContactId }) | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ContactId }) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ContactId })
      </td>
    </tr>

</table>

<br />Page @(Model.PageCount
< Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page=>Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter}))
```

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.GroupSortParm = sortOrder == "Group" ? "group_desc" : "Group";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }
        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        string thisUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var contacts = from s in db.ContactModels where s.UserId == thisUser select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            contacts = contacts.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString) || s.FirstName.Contains(searchString) || s.ContactGroup.Contains(searchString));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                contacts = contacts.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                break;
            case "Group":
                contacts = contacts.OrderBy(s => s.ContactGroup);
                break;
            case "group_desc":
                contacts = contacts.OrderByDescending(s => s.ContactGroup);
                break;
            default:
                contacts = contacts.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                break;
        }
        int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        var groups = contacts.Where(x => x.ContactGroup !=null).Select(x => x.ContactGroup).Distinct();
        ViewBag.Groups = new SelectList(groups);

        return View(contacts.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

I thought I could use `ViewBag.Groups` in order to keep track of the `ContactGroup`s belonging to the current user. This is used by `DropDownList` is View to display the `ContactGroup`s.

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, but I can't seem to see the solution. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

1. A view model for the view returned by the controller that has a property for #3.
2. An [HTML Helper](http://cpratt.co/html-editorfor-and-htmlattributes/) that goes in the Views\Shared folder.
3. An object that defines the properties in the HTML Helper.
4. In your controller populate object that defines your HTML Helper.